# How to connect CouchDb with HapiJs?

Tags: couchdb, hapi.js

I have an App written using the HapiJs framework for Node and want to connect it to a CouchDb databse, but am having trouble finding the code to do so.

Can anyone help me with the code to do that? What is the 'normal' way of doing that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you don't need any framework for couchdb. Everything is available via a rest api. Just use [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) module to make requests to the api. A few examples : -

**Read a document**

```
 request.get("http://localhost:5984/name_of_db/id_of_docuement",
        function(err,res,data){
      if(err) console.log(err);  
     console.log(data);
 });
```

**Read from a view**

```
    request.get(
    "http://localhost:5984/name_of_db/_design/d_name/_view/_view_name",
        function(err,res,data){
      if(err) console.log(err);  
     console.log(data);
 });
```

The entire api is documented [here](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/index.html)

There is no need to manage connections or to handle the opening and closing of database that you might be doing with other databases. Simply start couchdb and start making requests to from your application.

However if you find that making requests to the api directly is a bit cumbersome for you, then you can try using [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano) which provides a nicer syntax for doing things with couchdb.

**Some snippets of code**

All right so I am not familliar with hapi so I will just tell you how do do it with request.

Consider this example from the [docs](http://hapijs.com/tutorials)

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server(3000);
var request = require("request");

server.route({
method: 'GET',
path: '/',
handler: function (request, reply) {
    reply('Hello, world!');
}
});

server.route({
method: 'GET',
path: '/{name}',
handler: function (req, rep) {
         request.get("http://localhost:5984/name_of_db/id_of_docuement",
        function(err,res,data){
      if(err) console.log(err);  
     rep(data);
 });

}
});

server.start(function () {
console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

When you call the `/` endpoint it the request handler for it is executed. It makes a request to a couchdb endpoint to fetch a a document. You don't need anything to connect to couchdb besides that.

Comment: Ok, but what I want to know is what is the code to connect my app to the Couchdb database? Like when we write `var Hapi = require('hapi');`

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be the hapi-couchdb plugin (https://github.com/harrybarnard/hapi-couchdb).

Using it is a little more "hapi-like" than making direct calls into the Couch API directly.

Here's an example from the plugin documentation:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi'),
    server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8080
});

// Register plugin with some options
server.register({
    plugin: require('hapi-couchdb'),
    options: {
        url: 'http://username:password@localhost:5984',
        db: 'mycouchdb'
    }
}, function (err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error registering hapi-couchdb', err);
    } else {
        console.log('hapi-couchdb registered');
    }
});

// Example of accessing CouchDb within a route handler
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        var CouchDb = request.server.plugins['hapi-couchdb'];
        // Get a document from the db
        CouchDb.Db.get('rabbit', { revs_info: true }, function(err, body) {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(CouchDb.Error(error); // Using error decoration convenience method
            } else {
                reply(body);
            });
    }
});

server.start(function() {
    console.log('Server running on host: ' + server.info.uri);
});
```